# Center content vertically in Ionic?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I want to be able to center most anything vertically on a screen:

For example

- Forms
- Buttons

Is this possible to do with some custom css class?

Right now I am using the code below. It works but is not very good as I choose at which percentage the content will start. So I need one of these for every page and if content becomes longer I have to modify the percentage.

```
.loginForm .scroll {
  height: 100%;
}
.loginForm .loginForm-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to center content vertically. I'm often using the way to `transform` them. Let's say you got a container in which another element should be centered.

```css
.container {
  position: relative; /* required */

  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.center-me {
  display: block;
  font-family: Consolas;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;

  position: absolute; /* required */
  top: 50%; /* required */
  left: 50%;
  transform: 
    translateY(-50%) /* required */
    translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="center-me">
    center
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That didn't work for my code. I tried both with all fields and only the required fields. The content ended up getting compressed to the top left corner instead. Here is my HTML so that you can maybe see what I did wrong: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPvqgq

Comment: Here is the latest CSS I tried: 
.container {
  position: relative; /* required */
  height: 100%;
}
.center-me {
  display: block;
  position: absolute; /* required */
  top: 50%; /* required */
    translateY(-50%) /* required */
}

Answer (score 0):

You could do something with a little bit of JS, though I think @Jan Unld's answer is sufficient.

```js
calcMiddle = function () {
    var middleObject = document.querySelector('#middle'),
        middleHeight = middleObject.clientHeight / 2,
        middleWindow = window.innerHeight / 2,
        middleMargin = middleWindow - middleHeight;
    middleObject.style.marginTop = middleMargin + "px";
};

calcMiddle();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#middle {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #abcabc;
}
```

```html
<body onresize="calcMiddle();">
    <div id="middle">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a arcu sed neque volutpat lacinia mattis vitae nulla. Mauris in rutrum dui. Nullam nec dui rhoncus diam aliquam molestie. Nullam volutpat odio dignissim lorem ornare luctus. Aenean iaculis lectus venenatis aliquam porttitor. Etiam facilisis libero nec risus blandit aliquam. Donec sed ipsum nibh. Vestibulum sit amet accumsan ipsum. Maecenas viverra auctor orci, et scelerisque enim congue et.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/y7h60kr7/

Comment: You don't have t mo use JavaScript to achieve this. You can use plain CSS